# want to check owner of bigquery table

Tags: google-bigquery

Can someone assist me in determining who created the table, or the table's owner, in a big query using information_schema?

owner of nay table table who created that

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT user_email
FROM `region-australia-southeast2`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS
WHERE statement_type like 'CREATE_TABLE%'
```

the `like` clause gives you table created with select clause and also create table with ddl script

the `user_email` gives you the Email address or service account of the user who ran the job and hence can use this as the user who created the table.